# Dynamically add data into list box when we click add button

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate, jsp

Hibernate and Spring tags and jstl tags in our application. I have attached screen shot.

First list box I'm loading roles emails id's from database when I select email and click add the selected email should be add to second list box dynamically. When I want to remove, it should be remove dynamically. Please help me out I'm very new to developing such things.

Comment: There is no screen shot.

Answer (score 0):

To "move" an item from one list to an other dynamically (I think this mean without sending a request to the server) you need some java script.

Google for "jQuery Pick List"

- http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-picklist/
- http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/picklists/

Comment: can u give complete example on this

Comment: i will pasted code can u help me how to do Dynamically add data into list box when we click add button

Comment: @user1465744: no, Stack overflow works this way: You ask a question and show what you have tryed/done so far, and someone will help you to fix your problem. -- http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/